# JQuery - Reload function for dynamic content

Tags: jquery

The below zoom function is not working as I hoped. 
`elevateZoom()` is being called on the img element inside `.image`. 
When `.it-thumb` is clicked, `.image > img` and its id changes. But the zoomed image is still the first loaded image in `.image > img`.

Hope this is enough to explain what's going on. If needed I can post the html and the on click code that actually does the image change. But those are all working properly.

```
$('.item-img').elevateZoom();

  $('.it-thumb').on('click',function(){
    $('.item-img').trigger('elevateZoom.destroy'); // remove zoom 
    $(".item-img).elevateZoom(); 

 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="col_4 image column">

        <img id="513-4" class="item-img" src="images/355x/513-4.jpg" alt="Zoom test" data-zoom-image="images/large/513-4.jpg">

      <div class="col_12 column" id="thumbs">
          <div class="col_4 center column"><img id="513-1" class="it-thumb" src="images/90x/513-1.jpg" alt=""></div>       
          <div class="col_4 center column"><img id="513-2" class="it-thumb" src="images/90x/513-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <div class="col_4 center column"><img id="513-3" class="it-thumb" src="images/90x/513-3.jpg" alt=""></div>    
      </div>

</div>
```

Thumb click function:

```
$(".it-thumb").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var mainID = $(".item-img").attr("id");        

  $(".item-img").attr("src", "images/355x/"+id+".jpg").attr("id", id).attr("data-zoom-image", "images/large/"+id+".jpg");


  $(this).attr("src", "images/90x/"+mainID+".jpg").attr("id", mainID);

});
```

Comment: if you'r using an `id`... why do you need to append `.image > ` in the first place for `$(".image > #"+id).elevateZoom(); ` ? and you can simplify to `$(this).elevateZoom();` as you're taken the `id` from `$(this)` element

Comment: What type of run time errors did you get in the console?

Also, did you extend the jQuery prototype and added this method `elevateZoom()` to it before going ahead with execution?

Comment: @Mr.X I don't get any errors.

Comment: @ciprian So, I assume that this is a part of some plugin, right?

Comment: Yes ... this one: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Comment: Ok ... it's something like this: http://i.imgur.com/Bro7RMR.png Secret Wars loads first as the main image. When one of the below thumbs is clicked, the main image changes. But the zoom function still zooms on Secret Wars.

Comment: You should also provide relevant parts of your HTML

Comment: From plugin page:  `<img id="zoom_01" src="small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>` When the image changes, the `data-zoom-image` attribute also changes pointing to the correct large image.

Comment: @ArturFilipiak I can create a fiddle ... but I don't know how to load the zoom plugin in it.

Comment: Here is a fiddle base with the plugin loaded in: http://jsfiddle.net/z9o80Ldn/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z9o80Ldn/1/ - But looking at it now ... I don't think .image > img is such a good idea. Thank you for loading the plugin

Comment: Usually it's not a good idea to change the ID of an element.

Comment: I only use the id to change the image. Should I just add and remove a class? I don't really need the id.

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to achieve :) It's a shot in the dark: http://jsfiddle.net/tefyzb3n/ Something like this?

Comment: Yeah ... that's pretty much it. :) I m bad at explaining things.

Comment: Well, glad I could help! :)